# How to dynamically load class using namespaces/subdirectory in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3.1 app (with Ruby 1.9), I have a **Deployer1** class that is in a **worker** subdirectory below the **model** directory

I am trying to load/instantiate this class dynamically with this code:

```
clazz = item.deployer_class  # deployer_class is the class name in a string
deployer_class = Object.const_get clazz
deployer = deployer_class.new
```

If I dont use namespaces, eg something global like this:

```
class Deployer1
end
```

Then it works fine (deployer_class="Deployer1") - it can load the class and create the object.

If I try and put it into a module to namespace it a bit, like this:

```
module Worker
    class Deployer1
    end
end
```

It doesnt work (deployer_class="Worker::Deployer1") - gives an error about missing constant, which I believe means it cannot find the class.

I can access the class generally in my Rails code in a static way (Worker::Deployer1.new) - so Rails is configured correctly to load this, perhaps I am loading it the wrong way...

EDIT:
So, as per Vlad's answer, the solution I went for is:

```
deployer_class.constantize.new
```

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try using [`constantize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections/constantize) instead:

```
module Wtf
  class Damm
  end
end
#=> nil
'Wtf::Damm'.constantize
#=> Wtf::Damm
Object.const_get 'Wtf::Damm'
#=> Wtf::Damm
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad - just what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

`Object` does not know a constant named `Worker::Deployer1`, which is why `Object.const_get 'Worker::Deployer1'` doesn't work. `Object` only knows a constant `Worker`. What does work is `Worker.const_get 'Deployer1'`.

Vlad Khomisch's answer works, because if you look at the implementation of `constantize`, this is exactly what it does: it splits the string on `'::'` and recursively `const_get`'s.

Comment: Cool - thanks for that.  I must dig a little deeper into Ruby Classes and constants :)